# Is there a more optimized way to do a simple computation in java?

Tags: java, multiprocessing, largenumber

I am trying to figure out a way in order to solve this particular problem faster and in a more optimized way. I do not know if it is possible to have this code run on multiple cores and threads or if somehow I could offload it to GPU's but the faster this is able to compute the better.

```java
public class numberCounter 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Used only to check speed of calculation
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Initialized variables
        double x, y, z;

        //30 can be substituted out but i used it as a test. 
        //I am unable to calculate 31 and above.
        long t = (long) Math.pow(2, 30);

        //used later for counting
        long counter = 0;

        //starting number
        System.out.println("Number - " + t);

        for(int i = 1; i < t; i++)
        {
            x = i % 2;
            y = i % 3;
            z = i % 5;

            if(x*y*z > 0)
                counter++;
        }

        System.out.println();

        //prints out number of numbers that follow the rule above
        System.out.printf("Numbers: %.0f\n", counter);

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //prints out time taken
        System.out.println((end - start) + " ms");

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework question, so I'll give a few hints. Hint #1: you should be able to do this in constant time. Hint #2:what is the value for counter when t=30? When t=60?

Comment: It is technically a homework problem I gave myself to try and prove a mathematical point and I only used the time to see how long it would take to see if the optimizations would make it faster. t at 30 = 286331153. I am not able to compute above that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest burden is the loop, so it is best to be addressed if we want to gain something for optimization.
You have to reverse the problem, instead of looking for numbers indivisible by 2 or 3 or 5, we were looking for numbers divisible by 2 or 3 or 5. The resulting number of such numbers subtract all the numbers will give us the number of indivisible numbers by 2 or 3 or 5. In this way, we obtain an algorithm with a constant execution time. Execution time does not depend on the input.

```
public static long indivisbleBy_2or3or5(long t) {
    long x, y, z;

    //amount of numbers divisible by 2, and several for 3 and 5. 
    x = t / 2;

    //amount of numbers divisible by 3 - numbers divisible by 3 and 2 = amount of numbers divisible by 3, and several for 5.
    y = t / 3;
    y = y - y / 2;

    //amount of numbers divisible by 5 - numbers divisible by 5 and 2 - (numbers divisible by 5 and 3 - numbers divisible by 5 and 3 and 2)  = number only divisible by 5  
    z = t / 5;
    z = z - z / 2 - (z / 3 - z / (2 * 3) );

    //All numbers - (The amount of numbers divisible by 2, and several for 3 and 5 
    //+ The amount of numbers divisible by 3 and several for 5 + number only divisible by 5)
    //= indivisible by 2 or 3 or 5
    return t - (x + y + z);
}
```

I do not know whether the "pow" there is some optimization, but it is generally better to perform an action (2 ^ 15) ^ 2 which gives 15 operations than 2 ^ 30, which gives 29 operations. According to the principle of "divide et impera". :)

Comment: 2^x is equivalent to 1<<x. It is always a single ROL operation

Comment: at least in x86 SHL SRC,DST will shift DST register SRC times in a single operation or was it SRC by DST times?

Comment: This really helped a lot. Thank you!